# how does the "if" block in c work, If assign a value in "if" block ? Eg if(i=0){ //some code } will flow go inside the if block

Tags: c

how the "if" block in c will evaluate this . will code inside the "if" block will be executed?
Eg

```
int main(){
    int i;
if(i=0){
      //some code 
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't do this ever! Some compilers (`gcc` at least) even warn you when you do this. Second, the code will not be executed because the result of `a = n` is `n`, so, we have `if (0)`, which is always false.

Comment: You have an assignment in the `if` statement condition, and since the result of assigning zero to anything evaluates to zero or false, the body of the `if` statement is never executed. If you change `=` to `==` then you’re using an uninitialized variable and the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: i appreciate set answer to correct if it needs your meet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (i = 0)` would assign the value `0` to `i` and then it check whether the value of the expression (which is the value assigned, i.e. 0) is non-zero. In other words, it won't execute the body of the `if`. it'll just set i to 0. It'll also raise a warning on any decent compiler.

also , `if (i = 1)` would assign the value 1 to i and always execute the body. only a break (or exception) within the body would terminate it.